# How to pattern match a io.circe.Json object?

Tags: json, scala, circe

I want to compare two Jsons. For that I created a recursive function that uses Pattern matching.

Something like this:

```
(json1, json2) match {
  case (obj1: JsonObject, obj2: JsonObject) =>
    ...
  case (arr1: JsonArray, arr2: JsonArray) =>
    ...
  case _ =>
    ...
}
```

`json1` and `json2` are from the type `io.circe.Json`.

I tried different things:

- I did not find the representation of JsonArray
- JsonObject is not really related to JSON
- The related classes are package private, like

  ```
  private[circe] final case class JArray(value: Vector[Json])
  ```

My working solution uses the provided if-checks, like `case _ if expJson.isArray && resJson.isArray =>`.

Is there a better way?

Comment: AFAIK **circe** authors decided to hide the internal ADT, so you rather use combinators and cursors, similar to `IO`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks, I just checked the Cursor Classes are also package private - so no pattern matching either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're not supposed to match.

You can use methods `Json#fold`, `Json#arrayOrObject`, `Json#foldWith` or `Json#isArray/asArray/isObject/asObject`

```
json1.arrayOrObject(
  handleRest(),
  arr1 => json2.arrayOrObject(
    handleRest(),
    arr2 => handleArrays(arr1, arr2),
    _    => handleRest()
  ),
  obj1 => json2.arrayOrObject(
    handleRest(),
    _    => handleRest(),
    obj2 => handleObjects(obj1, obj2)
  )
)

def handleObjects(obj1: JsonObject, obj2: JsonObject) = ???
def handleArrays(arr1: Vector[Json], arr2: Vector[Json]) = ???
def handleRest() = ???
```

Classes `JNull`, `JBoolean`, `JNumber`, `JString`, `JArray`, `JObject` are package-private (the package is `io.circe`). If you really want to access them and match you can write some your code inside the package `io.circe`.